# Equivalence relations and cardinalities

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $ X $ be a set and $ R $ an equivalence relation on $P(X)$ s.t for each $ A $, $ B $ subsets of $ X $ it satisfies that $ A ~R~ B  \iff  (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) $ is finite.

I was asked to specify a set $X$ for which the relation $R$ on $P(X)$ has  countably equivalence classes s.t each of those is countable.

I struggle to follow the right intuition and if someone could shed some light (rather than an explicit example) I will be happy, thanks

Edit: I naively let $X = \mathbb{N}$ and tried to identify some attributes regarding $R$ which I failed

Comment: Does your definition of countable include finite?  If not, there is no solution.

Comment: We defined a set A to be countable if there exists a bijection from A to $\mathbb{N}$. Whats the intuition about not having a solution for this?

Comment: How large is $P(\Bbb N)$?  Then your second paragraph has to fail.

Comment: Thanks for saving my sanity

Comment: As soon as $X$ is infinite, there are uncountably many equivalence classes.

Comment: You mean it implies the set of all equivalence classes is uncountable? I can only see why it necessarily implies that there exists at least an uncountable one equivalence class

Comment: For other relations there might be only countably many classes, but then some will be uncountable.  $P(X)$ cannot be a countable union of countable sets or it would be countable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $ X$ is infinite and let $j \colon  \mathbb{N} \rightarrow  X$
be an injection.

Let $ {R'}$ be
the equivalence relation in $ P \left(\mathbb{N}\right)$
defined by

\begin{equation}A \  {R'} \  B \qquad  \Longleftrightarrow  \qquad  j \left(A\right) \  R \  j \left(B\right)\end{equation}

As $j \left(A {\Delta} B\right) = j \left(A\right) \  {\Delta} \  j \left(B\right)$, we have that

$A \  {R'} \  B$
if and only if $A {\Delta} B$ is finite,
where $ {\Delta}$ is the symmetric difference. Hence the
equivalence class of $ A$ for the relation $ {R'}$
is

\begin{equation}\text{Cl} \left(A\right) = \bigcup_{n  \geqslant  0} \left\{B \in  P \left(\mathbb{N}\right) , A \cap  \left[n , \infty \right[ = B \cap  \left[n , \infty \right[\right\}\end{equation}

hence $\text{Cl} \left(A\right)$ is a countable union of finite sets, hence it is countable.

Since $ P \left(\mathbb{N}\right)$ is the union of all equivalence classes
which are all countable, it follows that there are
uncountably many equivalence classes for $R'$, hence uncountably many equivalence classes for $R$.